# Exporting and loading models

Tags: python, tensorflow

System information
OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):

Mac os Sierra (10.12.5)

TensorFlow installed from:

Using pip

TensorFlow version (use command below):
1.2.1

The Problem:

I'm trying to save and restore a model trained from Python to Python. 
I've the model saved in three .chkpt files (meta, index and data-000000-of-00001) and I'm trying to read it into my session, save the model using add_meta_graph_and_variables and then read it again using the loader: `loader.load(session,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.TRAINING], pathToSaveModel)`.

This is my code:

First, I restore the weights from the three files containing "data", "index" and "meta" (the metagraph and the weights") into my session using saver restore:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as session:
    ##HERE IS THE CODE OF MY NETWORK (Very long)

    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #Load
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(session, "newModel.chkpt")

    features = loadFeatures(["cat2.jpg"])
    res = predictions.eval(
            feed_dict={
                x: features,
                keep_prob: 1.0, })
    print('Image {} has a prob {} '.format(image, res))

    b = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(pathToSaveModel)
    b.add_meta_graph_and_variables(session, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.TRAINING])
    b.save()
```

With this code, I've a good classification and finally a new folder containing the model saved with add_meta_graph_and_variables: 
[image: Folder with the model saved with]

Now, I want to use the saved model to classify, again, the same image. This time I used the loader instead the restore:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as session:
    ##HERE IS THE CODE OF MY NETWORK (Very long)

    #session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #Load
    from tensorflow.python.saved_model import loader
    loader.load(session, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.TRAINING], pathToSaveModel)

    features = loadFeatures(["cat2.jpg"])
    res = predictions.eval(
            feed_dict={
                x: features,
                keep_prob: 1.0, })
    print('Image {} has a prob {} '.format(image, res))
```

And here comes the problem:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value b_fcO
     [[Node: b_fcO/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@b_fcO"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](b_fcO)]]
```

If I've tried to use: session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) then it works but the classification is not valid, I think that the weights are not being exported / imported from the very beginning and after test many things I'm stuck here.

Any clues about what I'm doing wrong?.

Thanks in advance.

Update: 
This is how the model is in three files in the beginning: 
[image: ckpt files]

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things you should check are:

- What is pathToSaveModel?
- Where is the checkpoint file?
- open the checkpoint file with a text editor: to what folder does it point?
- is the path to the weights correct?

By going over these questions I was always able to find the mistake I made. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi rmeertens, I'm not sure about what chkpt file are you meaning. The three files chkpt at the beginning are binary, not text files, and is not contained any path inside them (as far as I can see).  I've debugged the code and inside loader the paths are being constructed ok.

Comment: As far as I know Tensorflow always saves the filenames of variables in a checkpoint file. https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables. Also: you might want to take another look here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder